# Optimizing bug in ARM Apple Clang on implicit casting double to byte

Tags: c++, clang++

I found a nasty bug in our C++ iOS application, which I suspect to be caused by a compiler bug on ARM based Apple Clang.

I was able to reproduce the bug in a MRE on a Mac M1 machine.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(double a=1000; a<10000; a*=1.1)
    {
        unsigned char d = a / 0.1;
        total += d;
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n", total);
}
```

Compiled without optimization, the test program always produces the same output:

```
% ./a.out            
Total: 3237
% ./a.out
Total: 3237
% ./a.out
Total: 3237
```

However, when compiling with optimization, the resulted number seems like random:

```
% clang -O3 test.cpp 
% ./a.out            
Total: 74841976
% ./a.out
Total: 71057272
% ./a.out
Total: 69828472
```

The Apple Clang version is 13.0:

```
% clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I believe the program does not have undefined behavior. So my questions:

- Is that really a compiler bug?
- Is the behavior also wrong on original (not Apple) Clang?
- Should I fill in a bug report?

Comment: Is it possible that you can show the assembly code, with and without optimization?

Comment: @RichardCritten "which is out of range for a unsigned char" -> "which might be out of range for an unsigned char"

Comment: @RichardCritten "unsigned char d = 1000 * 10.0; which is out of range for a unsigned char and therefore UB " -> "unsigned char d = 1000 * 10.0; which is out of range for a unsigned char on your platform and therefore UB "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does have undefined behavior.  When you do

```
unsigned char d = a / 0.1;
```

you are doing floating point to integer conversion which means [[conv.fpint]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv#fpint-1) applies and it states:

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

so once `a / 0.1` exceeds the max value of an `unsigned char` you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Great. But then what is the well defined way to convert a double to an out-of-range integer using modulo arithmetics?

Comment: @prapin: `fmod` would do it.

Comment: @Bathsheba: If you rule out negative values (and infinities and NaNs).

Comment: @prapin It depends on what you want the behavior to be.  If the value is too large do you want to just use the max value or do you want to get a value that is somewhere in the range of the data type?

Comment: @NathanOliver: The comment asks for “modulo arithmetics”, so presumably they want the truncated `double` value mapped to its residue modulo `UCHAR_MAX+1`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: as I tried to tell, I want a modulo 256 (number between 0 and 255) representation of the `double` value, even in case of a negative floating point.

Comment: @prapin [`fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) should work for you

Comment: This `[conv.fpint]/1` clause seems to be contradictory to the more general rule saying that unsigned integers never overflow, they wrap around. Therefore, the clause violates the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). I would consider this as a defect in C++ standard.

Comment: @prapin There is no rule that says unsigned integers never overflow.  There are rules that all arithmetic operations happen modulo 2^n.  Here we are not doing an operation, we are initializing so the floating point to integer conversion rule is the one we have to follow.

Answer (score 2):

It's an often forgotten rule, but the behaviour on converting a floating point to an out of range integral type is *undefined*.